# How do i make the variable bleed work with both of these events

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

```java
@EventHandler
public void onEntityDamageByEntityEvent(EntityDamageEvent event)
{

    if(Math.random()&lt;=0.02)
    {
        Entity e = event.getEntity();

        int bleed = plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(plugin,      new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                //Two percent chance you will bleed

                if(e instanceof Player)
                {
                    Player player = (Player) e;

                    player.damage(1.0D);
                    player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.CONFUSION, 200, 2));
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You are bleeding, find a bandage and heal yourself");

                    public void onPlayerEvent(PlayerInteractEvent event) { //ERROR HAPPENS ON THIS LINE ON THE PARENTHESES

                        Player player = event.getPlayer();
                        Action act = event.getAction();

                        if(event.getAction() == act.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR) {
                            if(player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.PAPER) {
                                plugin.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTask(bleed);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 20, 400);
    }
}
```

I am fully aware that I am not allowed to have a method inside of a method, but I do not know any other way to make this work.

The `bleed` variable on line 7 is supposed to correspond with the same one on line 22

The 2nd event is supposed to cancel the task in the first one.

The error I'm getting is: `Syntax error on "(" , ; expected`.

EDIT:

@AndrewG So, I tested out your code, and it is not working correctly, this is the whole source of the class i have: `

```
package com.aidan.TeamHeal;


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageByEntityEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffect;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;



public class BukkitListener implements Listener  {

Map<UUID, Integer> bleed = new HashMap<UUID, Integer>();

public static Bukkit plugin;

public BukkitListener(Bukkit instance) {
    plugin = instance;
}



@EventHandler
public void onEntityDamageByEntity(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {
    if(Math.random() <1) {
        Entity e = event.getEntity();
//          Entity z = event.getDamager();

        if(e instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) e;

            player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.BLINDNESS, 100, 1));   
        }
    }
}



 @EventHandler
    public void onEntityDamageByEntityEvent(EntityDamageEvent event) {

        if (Math.random() <= 1) {
            final Entity e = event.getEntity();

           int playersBleed = plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    // Two percent chance you will bleed

                    if (e instanceof Player) {
                        Player player = (Player) e;

                        player.damage(1.0D);
                        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.CONFUSION, 200, 2));
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You are bleeding, find a bandage and heal yourself");

                    }
                }
            }, 20, 400);
            bleed.put(e.getUniqueId(), new Integer(playersBleed));
        }
    }

    // Don't forget the @EventHandler annotation here too!
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerEvent(PlayerInteractEvent event) {

        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if (event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR) {
            if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.PAPER) {

                if(bleed.containsKey(player.getUniqueId())) {
                    Integer playersBleed = bleed.get(player.getUniqueId());
                    int playersBleedInt = playersBleed.intValue();
                    plugin.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTask(playersBleedInt);
                    player.sendMessage("YOu have been healed");



                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Why do you need that method there?

Comment: @Vandale I need the PlayerInteractEvent to cancel a task that makes the players bleed 1/2 hearts, I just don't know how to make it work correctly, the game im using it in is Minecraft.

Comment: For all who aren't familiar with what he's doing, he's writing a plugin using an API called CraftBukkit for a Minecraft Server. He was trying to use one method's variable inside another method, and he took the (interesting) approach of just putting the methods inside each other. Instead he should be using class-level variables.

Comment: Where and what is the error? And next time could you please comment, because editing doesn't show up in my notifications. Btw, are you sure that you registered your listener in the class that extends `JavaPlugin`?

Comment: Ok, I see what the issue is. You're using `Bukkit` as your plugin object, instead of `JavaPlugin`. The `Bukkit` object isn't actually meant to be used that way, and that's what's causing the errors. What you need to do is change your `plugin` object to be `JavaPlugin` instead of `Bukkit`. Then, when you are creating your `BukkitListener` class from your class that extends `JavaPlugin`, just pass it `this` for the `plugin` variable.

Comment: @AndrewG What is a plugin object, im very confused at the moment.

Comment: The `plugin` variable that you are using in your code to access the plugin, you're using the wrong thing as your `plugin`. You're using `Bukkit`, but you should be using `JavaPlugin`. That would fix all the other errors in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Is this Bukkit? If you are fully aware that you can't have a method inside of a method, why do you have one?

What your issue is is that you aren't making use of variables outside of methods. For example:

```
public class Bleed extends JavaPlugin {

    // Put the variable here, so it can be accessed by all the methods in the class.

    int bleed = 0; // Declare it here, use it elsewhere. We'll just have 0 as the default value.


    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityDamageByEntityEvent(EntityDamageEvent event) {

        if (Math.random() <= 0.02) {
            Entity e = event.getEntity();

            // Don't declare it again, just assign a value to it.
            bleed = plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    // Two percent chance you will bleed

                    if (e instanceof Player) {
                        Player player = (Player) e;

                        player.damage(1.0D);
                        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.CONFUSION, 200, 2));
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You are bleeding, find a bandage and heal yourself");

                    }
                }
            }, 20, 400);
        }
    }

    // Don't forget the @EventHandler annotation here too!
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerEvent(PlayerInteractEvent event) {

        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        Action act = event.getAction();

        if (event.getAction() == act.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR) {
            if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.PAPER) {
                // Assuming that the onEntityDamageByEntityEvent is called before this, bleed will have the value set in that method.
                // Let's make sure that actually happened, and bleed isn't still 0.
                if(bleed != 0) {
                    plugin.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTask(bleed);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The changes I made was mainly declaring a bleed variable in the scope of the class. (Stop here and go read all about variable scope in Java, it's SUPER important.) Now we have a variable that both methods can access, we take the other method out, and place it where it should be. The final thing I did is just make sure that we're only calling `cancelTask()` if a task has actually been set (Meaning that there's something actually inside `bleed`) using an `if` statement.

Now this introduces another issue, what if Player A started bleeding, then Player B started bleeding before Player A stopped? Now Player B's task is stored in `bleed` and player A's is gone. What we need is to store a different `bleed` variable for every player that's bleeding. For this, we can use a HashMap. Change this:

```
int bleed = 0;
```

to this:

```
Map<UUID, Integer> bleed = new HashMap<UUID, Integer>();
```

That creates a list, so we can store a player's ID next to the Integer object (Since we can't use primitives in a HashMap, we use the Integer object) that represents it's bleeding task.

Then, we change this:

```
bleed = plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    // Two percent chance you will bleed

                    if (e instanceof Player) {
                        Player player = (Player) e;

                        player.damage(1.0D);
                        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.CONFUSION, 200, 2));
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You are bleeding, find a bandage and heal yourself");

                    }
                }
            }, 20, 400);
```

to this:

```
int playersBleed = plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    // Two percent chance you will bleed

                    if (e instanceof Player) {
                        Player player = (Player) e;

                        player.damage(1.0D);
                        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.CONFUSION, 200, 2));
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You are bleeding, find a bandage and heal yourself");

                    }
                }
            }, 20, 400);
bleed.put(player.getUniqueId(), new Integer(playersBleed));
```

What that does is get the int from the task, put it inside a new Integer, and put it next to the player's ID. Then we change this:

```
if(bleed != 0) {
    plugin.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTask(bleed);
}
```

to:

```
if(bleed.containsKey(player.getUniqueId()) { // If that player is bleeding.
    Integer playersBleed = bleed.get(player.getUniqueId());
    int playersBleedInt = playersBleed.intValue();
    plugin.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTask(playersBleedInt);
}
```

Finally (hehe), you need to change this:

```
Entity e = event.getEntity();
```

to this:

```
final Entity e = event.getEntity();
```

This just allows code inside your runnable to get at the `e` variable.

Did that all make sense? I know I went kinda quick.. I'd be happy to explain any more in the comments.
I hope that helped, feel free to ask any questions you have in the comments.

Comment: Is this per character or a global event handler?

Comment: How so? All I did was copy a little of the code over. If you're referring to the if statement near the bottom, I assumed he could just take it out if he wanted to be cancelling a bunch of ghost tasks.

Comment: Technically this is a global event handler, this code would act funky on a server with more than one player. What you'd really need to do is to add a Map of some type storing player ID's with their bleed task codes. I'll update with the new code.

Comment: @AndrewG Thank you so much, i cannot explain how much gratitude i have for you. I learned alot from that post and will be testing this code sout soon, once again, thanks alot.

Comment: Yeah happy to help, I'll check back after a little while to see if you have any questions. @asperous.us I know right, but it seems like the best solution to me. Thanks for pointing out the fact that I needed some way to distinguish between players.

Comment: Really? You're REALLY checking for containsKey before a get?

Comment: Yes, I'm REALLY checking, because I know it will return `null` if nonexistent, and I don't want an NPE on the next few lines if so. And I didn't just check for `null` because I think that `containsKey()` is more readable, especially for someone who isn't very experienced with Java. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You were missing some curly braces which caused your error.

I basically just unwrapped some of your methods and this issue became obvious.

Also you had a scoping issue:

> "An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing scope that are not declared as final or effectively final." -- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

^ You'll see I have a final in `buildBleedHandler(final Entity e)` which allows my new Runnable to have access to that Entity e.

You will also need to use [`BukkitRunnable`](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html) to allow the Runnable to [cancel itself](https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/have-scheduler-task-cancel-itself.53617/).

Here is the code:

```java
public class BukkitListener extends JavaPlugin {
    public static Bukkit plugin;
    private static BukkitScheduler scheduler;
    final Float chanceYouWillBleed = 0.02f;
    final long bleedDelay = 20;
    final long bleedPeriod = 400;

    public BukkitListener(Bukkit instance) {
        plugin = instance;
        scheduler = Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler();
    }

    public static void bleedAction(Player player) {
        player.damage(1.0D);
        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.CONFUSION, 200, 2));
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You are bleeding, find a bandage and heal yourself");
    }

    BukkitRunnable buildBleedHandler(final Entity e) {
        return new BukkitRunnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (e instanceof Player) {
                    bleedAction((Player) e);
                }
            }

            @EventHandler
            public void onPlayerEvent(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR &&
                        event.getPlayer().getItemInHand().getType() == Material.PAPER) {
                    cancel();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityDamageByEntityEvent(EntityDamageEvent event) {
        if (Math.random() <= chanceYouWillBleed) {
            Entity e = event.getEntity();
            scheduler.scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, buildBleedHandler(e), bleedDelay, bleedPeriod);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put a method inside another method, inside another class!

Move `onPlayerEvent` after `onEntityDamageByEntityEvent`, and do not forget the `@EventHandler` annotation on it.

**But first, learn Java.** You can't play Bukkit without a knowledge of this programming language.